# Redis subscribe in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have a redis instance (`redis = Redis.new`) and when I paste this code into Rails console:

```
redis.subscribe('messages.create') do |on| 
  on.message do |event, data|
    puts data
  end
end
```

it blocks (starts waiting for messages)... but when I ctrl+c to break out of it and paste it again it immediately returns - why? So every time I interrupt it then the next run will not wait - it returns nil.